# Why is the passed in value undefined when accessing the map method?

Tags: javascript

When I run the snippet below in JSbin it says that capitalize won't work because the property is undefined. I looked at the documentation and it mentioned the use of the word 'this' but I am not quite sure if that applies here since the string value passed in is correct (console logged it to confirm). Why is the capitalize method not apple to work off the map value?

```
class bookTitle {   
    constructor(title) {
        this.title = title; // this creates the object ONCE, see top of jasmine file for explanation
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title; // retrieves the title string
    }

    set title(title) {
        this._title = this.titleCreator(title); // calls the method and sets title, see top of jasmine file for explanation
    }

    titleCreator(string) {

      if (string == null){
        return string; // catches first error
      }


        // Note that this isn't meant to be a fully fledged title creator, just designed to pass these specific tests
        var littleWords = ['and', 'do', 'the', 'a', 'an', 'in', 'of']; // These are the words that we don't want to capitalize

        var modifiedString = string
        .split(' ') // Splits string into array of words, basically breaks up the sentence
        .map(function(word,index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return this.capitalize(word); // capitalize the first word of the string
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) == -1) {
                return this.capitalize(word); // capitalize any words that are not little, the -1 is returned by indexOf if it can't find the word in the array
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                return word; // do not capitalize as this word is in the list of littleWords
            }
        })
        .join(' '); // Joins every element of an array into a string with a space inbetween each value. Basically you created a sentence from an array of words

        return modifiedString;

    }

    capitalize(word) {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        // This function just capitalizes the word given to it
    }
}

let bookTitles = new bookTitle();
bookTitles.title = 'inferno';
console.log(bookTitles.title); // The goal is to output Inferno
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` within your `map` refers to the function you're passing to `map`.  Use an arrow function `(word, index) => { ... }` instead and `this` should fall through to the parent class.

```
var modifiedString = string
        .split(' ') // Splits string into array of words, basically breaks up the sentence
        .map((word,index) => { // <-- ARROW FUNCTION
            if (index == 0) {
                return this.capitalize(word); // capitalize the first word of the string
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) == -1) {
                return this.capitalize(word); // capitalize any words that are not little, the -1 is returned by indexOf if it can't find the word in the array
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                return word; // do not capitalize as this word is in the list of littleWords
            }
        })
        .join(' ');
```

Comment: It works! I also managed to write it using 'this' at the end of the map callback too, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem :)  arrow functions FTW